# Python Naming Conventions for Dictionary or List Manipulations

Tags: python, list, dictionary, naming-conventions

In OOP coding, there is a long-standing naming convention to name accessor/mutator methods get_something and set_something. These directly access or manipulate the properties.

However, if the type of something is like a `dict` or `list` in Python, what is a better choice to name the manipulating-function?

For example,

1. I have a `list` named `booklist`, which contains the name of books that I want to read. I want to name the function that appending a new book into the `booklist`.

   ```
   booklist = ["Clean Code", "Code Complete"]

   def insert_book_into_booklist(new_book):
       booklist.append(new_book)
   ```

   Is there any better choice of `insert_book_into_booklist`? Just like `append_book_in_booklist` or `set_booklist`?

2. I have a `dict` named `booklist`. The key is the name of books that I want to read and the value is the International Standard Book Number (ISBN). I want to name the function that inserts a new book into the `booklist`.

   ```
   booklist = {"Clean Code": "9789862017050", "Code Complete": "9789536185344"}

   def insert_book_into_booklist(new_book, isbn):
       if new_book not in booklist:
           booklist[new_book] = isbn
   ```

   Is there any better choice of `insert_book_into_booklist`? Just like  `set_booklist`?

Thank you.

Comment: how about *dropping* `'book'`? What else could you insert in your `booklist`?

Comment: not sure about naming conventions, but there are a couple of elementary errors in your snippets. In the first, the argument to `booklist.append` should be `new_book`, and in the second you need `{...}` around the dict, not `[...]` (what you have there is actually invalid syntax.)

Comment: also your first function is just a "wrapper" for `booklist.append`, and I put "wrapper" in quotes because, unlike most wrappers, it doesn't actually add *any* functionality that the wrapped function doesn't already do. So why make a new function here?

Comment: @RobinZigmond Sorry for that typo first. It should be a complex class that has a variable `booklist` and the function. Since this is a fake case to avoid to leak the commercial confidential, I simplify the code.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Thanks for the suggestion!
However, I doubt which Verb "insert, append or set" should be used will be more proper rather than a Noun.

Comment: I don't know if you have this freedom, but I suggest to use ISBN as key in the `dict`, ISBN is supposed to be a unique code, different books can have the same name and `dicts` don't allow duplication of keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've mentioned OOP, lets pretend, that your "booklist" is a member of a class:

```
class BookList(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.booklist = []
```

So, if you want to add new book into your list, name your method as a verb, that doing what you need, for example "add_book". Also, you don't need to add "_into_booklist", bacause your class is a BookList itself and this is enough to understand where the book would be added:

```
class BookList(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.booklist = []

    def add_book(book):

        self.booklist.append(book)
```

Also, you can make this method work with ISBN:

```
class BookList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        # creating dict, not list
        self.booklist = {} 

    def add_book(book, isbn):

        self.booklist[book] = isbn
```

Also, as Ev. Kounis said in comment, you can omit "_book" part of method, and leave just "add", but if your class would became more complex in future, this name could get ambiguos. For example, if you have "add_book" method, you can add "add_books" method later (for adding lots of books at a time), and the meaning of that names are easy to understand. But if you short it down, to "add", it'll be less clear, what does this method adds actually.

Comment: Since the booklist had been a member variable of a class already. Is it proper to be a subclass of the outer class?

Comment: Do you mean "Subclass a list" ? Of course, you can do so, but in such a specialized case, I'd rathen not recommend it.

Comment: Subclassing of base classes, like a list or dict should be made if you want to use it in some places, where usual list or dict was used before, but base functionality wasn't anough. For example, if you want to implement dict, which would have keys always sorted alphabetically

Comment: If your BookList is an abstraction for the real hand-written books list, soon it would have functionality, that you can't put into list or dict paradigme. For example, if you add indexing by ISBN, what should be implemented as another class member, isbn_index= {}, which would have isbn numbers as keys, and book names as values. And now It has two dicts in an object, but if you didn't inherited it from list/dict, everything is ok

Comment: Ohh, you got me wrong. I mean since it is a big project, there had been several objects. Is it proper to add a class to one object?
For example, I have a class `Person` and the class had the `booklist` variable. Following your suggestion before, I should let the `booklist` become a class `Booklist` which has the variable `booklist` and the function `add_book` and initialize the instance in the class `Person`. Is it a correct way?

Comment: Yes, this is correct way, with a single clarification: Person in your case should have membed field booklist which is an instance of class BookList, not the class. And from this point of view, for Person there are no need to know, what is inside BookList, is it booklist, or _booklist, or m_booklist. Person just use add_book method, when it's needed, and booklist incapsulated inside of BookList, like in a black box

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much!